# Show instance for a dependent type

Tags: haskell, singleton-type

I am playing with dependent types in ghc 8, and I am running into a problem creating a Show instance for my type.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack exec --resolver=lts-7.14 --package singletons -- ghci
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeInType, TemplateHaskell, LambdaCase, TypeApplications #-}

import Data.Kind
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits

 data EmailAddress :: Symbol -> Symbol -> * where
  EmailAddress :: (KnownSymbol a, KnownSymbol b) => EmailAddress a b 

-- works
testEmail :: EmailAddress "blah" "blah.com"
testEmail = EmailAddress
```

I wanted to be able to show my address.

```
instance Show (EmailAddress a b)
  where show = showEmailAddress

showEmailAddress :: forall a b. EmailAddress a b -> String
showEmailAddress = \case
  EmailAddress -> symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy a) ++ "@" ++ symbolVal (Proxy :: Proxy b)

test1 = show testEmail -- works
```

Now I want to make a runtime `EmailAddress` from a user supplied string.  To start out I will get an address from a singleton.    Just taking one string for now.

```
fromString' :: Sing i -> EmailAddress i i
fromString' = \case
  SSym -> EmailAddress

test2 = fromString' @"asdf" sing -- works
```

The final piece of the puzzle is that I feel like I should be able to do something like the following.

```
fromString :: String -> EmailAddress a a
fromString str = case toSing str of
   SomeSing s -> fromString' s
```

But it doesn't work.  No matter what type signatures I apply to various parts of the function, I cannot get it to typecheck, I always get the following error `Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’` error on the following code.

```
fromString1 :: String -> EmailAddress a a
fromString1 str = case toSing str of
   SomeSing s -> fromString' s

fromString2 :: forall a. String -> EmailAddress a a
fromString2 str = case toSing str of
   SomeSing (s :: Sing a) -> fromString' s

fromString3 :: forall a. String -> EmailAddress a a
fromString3 str = case toSing str of
   (SomeSing s :: Sing (a :: Symbol)) -> fromString' s
```

This is the full error.  I don't understand where the `a1` is coming from in this.

```
Existentials5.hs:45:20: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      fromString3 :: forall (a :: Symbol). String -> EmailAddress a a
    at Existentials5.hs:43:16
  ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      SomeSing :: forall k k1 (k2 :: k1) (a :: k). Sing a -> SomeSing k,
    in a case alternative
    at Existentials5.hs:45:5
  Expected type: EmailAddress a a
    Actual type: EmailAddress a1 a1
• In the expression: fromString' s
  In a case alternative: (SomeSing s) -> fromString' s
  In the expression:
    case toSing str of { (SomeSing s) -> fromString' s }
• Relevant bindings include
    s :: Sing a1 (bound at Existentials5.hs:45:14)
    fromString3 :: String -> EmailAddress a a
      (bound at Existentials5.hs:44:1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fromString :: String -> EmailAddress a a` is impossible. `fromString @a ""` would give us `KnownSymbol a` for any `a`, which can't happen, because GHC erases all types from programs, including `Symbol`-s. We can't just conjure a runtime `String` corresponding to `a`. This is the reason why we have to use singletons in the first place.

From another perspective, the issue with `String -> EmailAddress a a` is that the input `String` can't be used in any meaningful way, because we need a `KnownSymbol a` output for a particular `a`.

If we have non-singleton runtime data, we can convert that to an existential singleton with `toSing`. We can then do runtime checks to learn about properties of the resulting singleton.

Comment: What lead me to try to do this was this tutorial: https://blog.jle.im/entry/practical-dependent-types-in-haskell-2.html.  He uses it to generate types at runtime.  But it lost me around the `SomeSing` portion.  I can't seem to find any intuition for how it is meant to be used.

Comment: The intuition should ideally come from dependent type theory, because GHC's singletons are a complicated and inconvenient approximation of that. There isn't a lot of beginner materials, however. [This](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) seems good but it's not free. You can look at [these](http://people.inf.elte.hu/divip/AgdaTutorial/Index.html) [two](http://oxij.org/note/BrutalDepTypes/) Agda tutorials, but they're a bit out of date tooling wise and more geared towards formalization than programming.

Comment: You could also look at [Software Foundations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html), which is very thorough and beginner friendly, but also has a focus on proofs and formalization, and Coq is more alien to Haskellers than Idris or Agda.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll be taking a long look at all of these.